# C# LINQ pivoting on table

Tags: c#, linq

I have following input data:

```
type    name    dept    salary
senior  ABC     123     2000
junior  ABC     456     1000
senior  IJK     456     3000
senior  LMN     123     2000
junior  LMN     123     1500
senior  STQ     123     2000
```

I desire following pivoted output:

```
name    dept    junior_salary   senior_salary
ABC     123     0               2000
ABC     456     1000            0
IJK     456     0               3000
LMN     123     1500            2000
STQ     123     0               2000
```

Following is the LINQ code I have written:

```
List<Posting> posting = getData();
posting.GroupBy(x=>new{x.type, x.name, x.dept})
       .Select(x=>new {
             name = x.Key.name,
             dept = x.Key.dept,
             junior_salary = x.Where(z=>x.Key.type=="junior").Sum(y=>y.salary),
             senior_salary = x.Where(z=>x.Key.type=="senior").Sum(y=>y.salary)
         }).ToList();
```

This is giving me incorrect results. Following are the results I am getting

```
name    dept    junior_salary   senior_salary
ABC     123     0               2000
ABC     456     1000            0
IJK     456     0               3000
LMN     123     0               2000
LMN     123     1500            0
STQ     123     0               2000
```

Here's a fiddle I have created to run the example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QCbyyD

Need help.

Comment: *incorrect results*? And what do you expect us to do with that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
var pivotList =
    posting
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.name, x.dept })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            name = x.Key.name,
            dept = x.Key.dept,
            junior_salary = x.Where(z => z.type == "junior").Sum(y => y.salary),
            senior_salary = x.Where(z => z.type == "senior").Sum(y => y.salary)
        })
        .ToList();
```

You just shouldn't have grouped by `type`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pivotList = posting.GroupBy(x=>new{x.name, x.dept})
   .Select(x=>new {
         name = x.Key.name,
         dept = x.Key.dept,
         junior_salary = x.Where(z=>z.type == "junior").Sum(y=>y.salary),
         senior_salary = x.Where(z=>z.type == "senior").Sum(y=>y.salary)
     }).ToList();
```

Fix is to remove type from group by clause.

Comment: You don't need the name checks since you're grouping on name all the values in the group will match the name in the key.  Also you should specify that the fix is to remove type from the grouping.